# Multi objective optimization is giving wrong results

Tags: linear-programming, binary-variable, multi-objective-optimization

I am trying to solve a multi objective optimization problem. I have a set of nodes belonging to different counties and each node is associated with some cost and some priority. I want to select the nodes such that cost of selected nodes is minimized and nodes with higher priority are selected. At each county, a minimum number of nodes should be selected.

\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}  & c^T x \\
\text{maximize}  & p^T x \\
\text{subject to}&  \sum_i x_{i} >=  \alpha_k, \quad \forall x_i \in C_k, \quad \forall k \in \{C_1,C_2,C_3,....,C_k\} \\
\ &0 \le x \le 1.
\end{array}
`c` is the cost array, `p` is the priority array, `x` is binary design variable and `C` is a county. The constraint means that in a given county C, the count of nodes selected should be atleast `alpha`.

I have taken the approach of binary integer programming. Each node is encoded as a binary variable where 0 means node is not selected and 1 means node is selected.

I am using [pymoo](https://pymoo.org/) to model this problem and the problem is formulated as follows:

```
class NodeProblem(Problem):
    def __init__(self, nodes:List[int], node_priorities:Dict[int,int], county_node_bounds:Dict[int,List[int]], county_nodes:Dict[int,List[int]], node_cost:Dict[int, float], **kwargs):
        self.nodes = np.array(nodes)
        self.node_priorities = node_priorities
        self.county_node_bounds = county_node_bounds
        self.county_nodes = county_nodes
        self.priorities = np.array(list(node_priorities.values()))
        self.cost = np.array(list(node_cost.values()))
        super().__init__(n_var=len(nodes), n_obj=2, n_ieq_constr=len(county_node_bounds), xl=0, xu=1, vtype=bool,  **kwargs)
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_index(arr1, arr2):
        """
        Return the index of elements present in arr2 ndarray as per arr1 ndarray.
        """
        sort = np.argsort(arr1)
        rank = np.searchsorted(arr1, arr2, sorter=sort)
        return sort[rank]

    def _evaluate(self, X, out, *args, **kwargs):
        # Shape of X is (pop_size, n_var)
        # objective value for each member of population

        cost_obj = np.dot(X, self.cost) # Shape after calculation is (pop_size,)

        priority_obj = np.dot(X, self.priorities)
        out["F"] = np.column_stack([cost_obj, -priority_obj])
        # Shape of constrs should be (pop_size, self.n_constr)
        constrs = []
        for c,target in self.county_node_bounds.items():
            node_cds = [ndc for ndc in self.county_nodes[c]]
            node_idxs = self.get_index(self.nodes, np.array(node_cds))
            a = target - np.sum(X[:, node_idxs], axis=1)
            constrs.append(a)
        out["G"] = np.column_stack(constrs)
```

My pareto front comes out as follows where first column is cost and second column is priority:

```
[[2365.51796736, -346.]
 [3004.5990833,  -383.]
 [3826.76396175, -414.]
 [3383.5413055,  -398.]
 [3447.82173955, -399.]
 [5397.57485522, -437.]
 [4400.71535067, -426.]
 [2648.00046736, -366.]
 [2366.60434547, -347.]]
```

The resulting pareto front is not meeting the standards. The priority values are coming out as negative. Is this because I have changed the sign of priority objective `priority_obj` to maximize it as `Pymoo` gives only `minimize` function? If negative sign just represents `maximize`, then also the result is not correct. For example, the highest cost value of 5397.57485522 has the highest priority 437. Similarly, the lowest cost value of 2365.51796736 has the lowest priority 346. But it should be the other way around.

Is my formulation wrong or I am not understanding something about optimization?

Comment: I didn't downvote but you should know community members don't need to state their reason for downvote. It is already provided (hover your mouse over the upvote/downvote buttons to see the tooltip).  I wouldn't worry too much about it.  Good questions attract upvotes over time.  Poor questions tend to attract downvotes overtime.  Just focus on quality all will be well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems right to me. If you want to maximise priority, you would have to sacrifice cost-wise. Hence, the costs goes up. If you want to minimise costs, you cannot select all the high-priority nodes, hence the total priority goes down. All the other solutions are non-dominated compromises between costs and priority.

I haven’t used pymoo before, but it seems you are right that it converts $\max f(x)$ to $-\min -f(x)$.

Comment: Can you explain in terms of data obtained in the pareto front ?

Comment: I was thinking if cost goes up then priority should decrease and if cost goes down then priority should increase. Why this thought is wrong as per you ?

Comment: @MSS Because if priority goes up at the same time as costs go down, you will end in an *ideal solution*, which optimises both objectives at the same time. If such an ideal solution exists (it usually doesn’t) then it’s not really a bi-objective problem as there is no conflict between the objectives. Multi objective optimisation is used when you have conflicting objectives, and the Pareto front gives you the “trade off curve” of the rational compromises between the objectives.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how pymoo works under the hood but the moment you are minimizing something like $g(x) = c^Tx - p^Tx $ without any scaling or hierarchial factor, it would minimize the whole func.
Rather you choose to $z= \min -p^Tx$ separately along with the constraint & then minimize the cost with $z \ge -p^Tx$ as additional constraint with the country selection one.

Comment: Can you tell me more on how to do scaling or adding heirarchial factor? It would be much appreciated. Also if you can provide some links for me to go through.

Comment: @MSS please check the below link. https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/working_with_multiple_obje.html. Then there's something called Bilevel optimization. Check this one: https://optimization-online.org/2021/06/8450/

Answer (score 1):

Pymoo always [minimize](https://pymoo.org/interface/index.html) so, as you did, it is needed to convert *max priority* to *min -priority*. If your results are expressed in terms of *priority* instead of *-priority*, and sorted in base of the first column, you have:

| Cost | Priority |
| --- | --- |
| 2365.51796736 | 346 |
| 2366.60434547 | 347 |
| 3004.5990833 | 383 |
| 3004.5990833 | 383 |
| 3383.5413055 | 398 |
| 3447.82173955 | 399 |
| 3826.76396175 | 414 |
| 4400.71535067 | 426 |
| 5397.57485522 | 437 |

Which looks like the right result. Better cost results (ie, lesser costs) imply worse priority results (ie, lesser priority) and viceversa.